# Dynamically filtered columns in excel possible?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-365

I have a table - 300 rows & 47 columns.  The task is to filter the data based on 3 dependent drop down lists. Hopefully not using PQ or macros, is it possible to create a filter formula that dynamically selects the columns and column values?

[image]

```
 =filter(D2:AX300),(D2:AX2="Column Name")*(D3:AX300="Input Name")
```

```
 =filter(Table_1),(Table_1([@["Column Name")*(Table_1="Input Name")
```

Some various iterations of that to incorporate all possible 6 conditions. I'm a little out of my depth on this, so looking for some help.

Comment: Assuming the label `Sort By` is in cell `B2`: `=FILTER(Table1,(INDEX(Table1,,MATCH(C4,Table1[#Headers],0))=D4)*(INDEX(Table1,,MATCH(C5,Table1[#Headers],0))=D5)*(INDEX(Table1,,MATCH(C6,Table1[#Headers],0))=D6))`

Comment: Thank you very much Spectral!  It works.

While I have you, any thoughts on how I could make it so I could use 1,2, or all three of the filter rows?

Comment: `=LET(all,SEQUENCE(ROWS(Table1),,1,0),FILTER(Table1,(IF(D4="",all,XLOOKUP(C4,Table1[#Headers],Table1)=D4))*(IF(D5="",all,XLOOKUP(C5,Table1[#Headers],Table1)=D5))*(IF(D6="",all,XLOOKUP(C6,Table1[#Headers],Table1)=D6)),"Invalid Filter Criteria"))`

Comment: Sorry for the delay Spectral, life got in the way.  Thank you for this!  What are you referring to when you say "all"?